# Ionic-AngularJS: Emitting Event To Parent Only ReBroadcasts To Child That Emitted Event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, events, angularjs-scope

This may all sound a bit vague, but I am still learning and trying to understand how this works.

I started working with a 'side menu' starter ionic project, and it came already setup with a urlrouter config with an 'app' abstract state/view/controller and some additional states with their own controllers.

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })


  .state('app.home', {
    url: "/home",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.page2', {
    url: "/page2",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/page2.html",
        controller: 'Page2Ctrl'
      }
    }
  });
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
})
```

In the App Controller (AppCtrl), I am listening for an event called repeatMyEvent, and it broadcasts an event called myEvent.

I have a listener in each of the other controllers for the myEvent event. When I emit the repeatMyEvent event from either of the other controllers (I have a button on the template that calls the testEmit() function), I am only seeing the controller that emitted the repeatMyEvent event respond to the myEvent event. It also seems that maybe it is only the controller whose view is currently visible is responding to it. However, I am expecting all controllers to respond to it.

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout) {
  // Form data for the login modal


  $scope.$on('repeatMyEvent', function(event, args) {
    console.log('repeatMyEvent event received');


    $scope.$broadcast('myEvent');

  });



})

.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {


  $scope.$on('myEvent', function(event, args) {
    console.log('HomeCtrl received myEvent');


  });

  $scope.testEmit = function() {
    $scope.$emit('repeatMyEvent');
  }


})

.controller('Page2Ctrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {


    $scope.$on('myEvent', function(event, args) {
        console.log('Page2Ctrl received myEvent');


    });

    $scope.testEmit = function() {
        $scope.$emit('repeatMyEvent');
    }


})

;
```

The only way I can make sense of this is that the controller for the abstract state isn't a singleton, and each of my controllers has their own version of it. Or have I completely misunderstood how $scope is supposed to work in relation to controllers?

And a follow up to all of that is how do I get this to work so that all controllers respond to broadcast messages from AppCtrl.

NOTE: I've also tried $scope.$root and I get the same behaviour.

Comment: The way your state config is setup, there will only be one controller active at the same time. Since you are replacing the view with new content every time the same changes.

Comment: @Wawy Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. Its just like that because that is how the 'starter' project was created. Is there a way to not make happen, or would it require a completely different setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to solve the specific communication problem because, as @Wawy pointed out in a comment on my original post,

> The way your state config is setup, there will only be one controller
>   active at the same time. Since you are replacing the view with new
>   content every time the page changes.

So to handle my specific issue (which was to get one controller to tell another controller to refresh its data), I just reorganized my code to have the data refresh function placed in AppCtrl, and then each of the other controllers can just emit an event to tell it to execute the data refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Controllers are instantiated, with $scope DI'd => [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)
( not singletons );

From what I can see in your router, you have three separate pages, each with their own url. I am curious as to why you are trying to get your controllers to cross talk when their specific DOM's are not even rendered.

If you must maintain some type of data object for each page when loaded you can create a factory/service that runs on initial app load and contains your value(s). Then just DI into each controller that needs that service's data.

Also, this is how broadcast and emit work.

```
                   3
               --------
              |        |
             ---     ----
            1   |    2   |
          ---  ---  --- ---
          |  | |  | | | | |
```

Check out this tree. How do you answer the following questions?
**note:** There are other ways, but here we'll discuss broadcast and emit.
Also, when reading below text assume each number has it's own file (directive, controller) e.x. one.js, two.js, three.js.

1. How does **1** speak to **3**?

In file one.js

```
scope.$emit('messageOne', someValue(s));
```

In file three.js

```
scope.$on('messageOne', someValue(s));
```

2. How does **2** speak to **3**?

In file two.js

```
scope.$emit('messageTwo', someValue(s));
```

In file three.js

```
scope.$on('messageTwo', someValue(s));
```

3. How does **3** speak to **1** and/or **2**?

In file three.js

```
scope.$broadcast('messageThree', someValue(s));
```

In file one.js && two.js ***whichever file you want to catch the message***.

```
scope.$on('messageThree', someValue(s));
```

4. How does **2** speak to **1**?

In file two.js

```
scope.$emit('messageTwo', someValue(s));
```

In file three.js

```
scope.$on('messageTwo', function( event, data ){
  scope.$broadcast( 'messageTwo', data );
});
```

In file one.js

```
scope.$on('messageTwo', someValue(s));
```

**HOWEVER**

When you have all these nested child nodes trying to communicate like this, you will quickly see many $on's $broadcast's, and $emit's. Here is what I like to do.

**In PARENT NODE** ( three in this case... )

So, in file three.js

```
scope.$on('pushChangesToAllNodes', function( event, message ){
  scope.$broadcast( message.name, message.data );
});
```

Now in any of the child nodes you only need to **$emit** the message or catch it using **$on**.

**NOTE:** It is normally quite easy to cross talk in one nested path without using $emit, $broadcast, or $on, which means most use cases are for when you are trying to get **1** to communicate with **2** or vice versa.

4. How does **2** speak to **1**?

In file two.js

```
scope.$emit('pushChangesToAllNodes', sendNewChanges());

function sendNewChanges(){
  return { name: 'talkToOne', data: [1,2,3] };
}
```

In file three.js

```
We already handled this one remember?
```

In file one.js

```
scope.$on('talkToOne', function( event, arrayOfNumbers ){
  arrayOfNumbers.forEach(function(number){
    console.log(number);
  });
});
```

You will still need to use $on with each specific value you want to catch, but now you can create whatever you like in any of the nodes without having to worry about how to get the message across the **parent gap**.

Hope this helps...

Comment: My reason for wanting them to cross talk was because I wanted an action in one controller to tell another controller to refresh its data. I just recently found, though, that if I put the data refresh code in the AppCtrl and maintain the data there then I don't have this issue anymore.